# How to install multiple ttf fonts for system-wide usage?

Tags: fonts, .ttf

I had "WinFonts" folder in home directory including many true type fonts (.ttf) which I would like to install to be applied for use widely across Ubuntu system and apps.
I need help guiding me to make this step?

Answer (score 12):

Installing TTF fonts system wide it's not difficult. You just need to create a directory inside one of the system font directories (you find them listed in `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`), put there your `*.ttf` fonts and then update system font cache with `fc-cache -fv` (With the options `-f` for *Force  re-generation of cache files* and `-v` for *Verbose*).

As suggested by @emk2203 you should put custom fonts in a subdirectory of `/usr/local/share/fonts`, so it's easy to tell them apart from distributor provided fonts (they are in `/usr/share/fonts`), and it's easier to backup or restore them if needed.

Step by step:

1. Create your custom fonts directory:

   `sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/fonts/truetype`
2. Copy your `*.ttf`fonts there:

   `sudo cp ~/myfonts/*.ttf /usr/local/share/fonts/truetype/`
3. Update system font cache:

   `sudo fc-cache -fv`

If you want to add more fonts later, just copy them to your `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype/` directory and update system font cache as above.

Comment: and don't forget that extension also are case sensitive. So for example copy `TTF` files also.

Comment: Right. To avoid this kind of annoying case problems, it may be a good idea to stick with a case convention for these files, i.e. use only lower case extensions.

Comment: FYI I didn't need sudo - so perhaps try without first

Comment: @ErichBSchulz this is because font cache are stored both system wide (in `/var/cache/fontconfig/`) and per-user (in `~/.cache/fontconfig`). If you have only one user on your system both commands will work. If you have more users, you may prefer to generate the cache once for everyone, using `sudo`.

Comment: For a lot of reasons, it's better to use directories specifically designed to hold user- or site-specific content, instead of distributor-specific content. Put your fonts (in appropriate subdirectories) in `/usr/local/share/fonts` instead. It exists for a reason.
If you decide to reinstall a system, you have everything you installed yourself in `/usr/local` for reference and backup.

Comment: I updated the answer including your suggestion. Thanks!